# I want to include google maps in my html page using ng-include

Tags: html, angularjs

i tried but i'm getting error like this ...

```
    ReferenceError: google is not defined
            at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:2536), <anonymous>:15:1)
            at eval (native)
            at Function.n.extend.globalEval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:2536)
            at n.fn.extend.domManip (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:17188)
            at n.fn.extend.append (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:14846)
            at m (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:136:287)
            at Object.enter (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:136:235)
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:158:3
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:100:347
            at i (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:437)
        maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&_=1420810087262:8 


   Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

**This is my html code...for includeing map using ng-include**

```
<html>
...
<div ng-include="'map.html'"></div>
...
</html>
```

**This is my map code...(map.html)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 19,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.994866,80.201111),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
                                mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:350px;height:200px;"></div>
```

what should i do ??
please help me ...

Comment: Please show your code to us.

Comment: you use the <script> tag to import any internal or external scripts to your project, like the google API, you use ng-include to include a static html page/snippet into another html page. refer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: hi rajasimon ...i have updated my Code above...

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but do use http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps. This way you have an Angular way of doing it, with data bindings to markers and other goodies.